# Changing Android BottomNavigationItemView icon

Tags: android, tabbar, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` that provides a tabbar on Android. I want to change the icon of it programatically which I've tried to do using the following

```
BottomNavigationItemView organisationTab = findViewById(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
organisationTab.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bank_feeds_uk));
```

This works but when i select any item on the tabbar, it reverts back to the original.

I tried to set it again on the onclick listener but it keeps reverting back to the original, i've tested this on a blank project to make sure nothing in my current code is doing anything weird.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `NaviagtaionViewItem` by getting its order in the `BottomNavigationView` menu

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_bank_feeds_uk);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful. 

Changing SetIcon worked until i selected the menu again, your code made the icon stick :)